# Update и Insert

Tags: sql, postgresql

Когда я вставляю (Insert) строки(записей) в таблицу, после запроса я вижу такое:
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Что означает 0 и что означает 4?
**Как я понял вторая цифра это количество вставленный строк(записей), а вот что такое 0(первая цифра)?**

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

**У Update как я понял, пишется Update 1 если изменилась строка(запись) т.к в роли 1 выступает true, а если Update 0, то в роли 0 выступает false. Поправьте если я ошибься**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Эти строки [приходят от процесса](https://github.com/postgres/postgres/blob/REL_11_STABLE/src/backend/tcop/pquery.c#L170) выполнявшего запрос и бывают следующих видов:

> SELECT X

Число X обозначает строк в результате (не надо его пытаться парсить, по протоколу число строк и отдельным полем приходит)

> UPDATE X

Число строк, который изменил update запрос (только на самом верхнем уровне если говорить про CTE).

> DELETE X

Полностью аналогично UPDATE

> INSERT Y X

Число X - число строк, которые вставил запрос.
Число Y - OID вставленной строки, если таблица была объявлена with oids и вставлена была только одна строка.

Сразу замечу, что OID для пользовательских таблиц давно объявлены устаревшими и удалены в postgresql 12. Число в результате, впрочем, остаётся пока для совместимости, но будет всегда 0.

Comment: Извините, вопрос не по теме, но где я могу на RuSO спросить несколько вопросов по ioS разработке, типа обсуждения? А то я не нашел ТИП темы обсуждение на этом сайте

Answer (score 1):

При вставке возвращается OID (Object identifier) вставленной строки, но он не 0, только если вставилась 1 строка [[1]](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.0/sql-insert.html).

При обновлении возвращается количество обновлённых строк [[2]](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.0/sql-update.html).